# Connection timeout when loging into vcenter through vsphere client

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi, vcenter, esx

I am newbie to VMware. When I am longing into the VCenter I am getting "Connection time out" in first 3 attempts, after 3 attempts I am able to Login to VCenter.

I did some troubleshoot and in vcenter changed  the Client to server time extended to 300sec. But still I am facing same issue. Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a developer-specific issue. Consider posting on https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/. Read about the communities (https://stackoverflow.com/tour https://serverfault.com/tour) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting by IP or hostname? Make sure DNS is OK. Are you using a standalone MSSQL server? Windows server built-in MSSQL? Is this VCSA (linux appliance)?

If Windows, did you reboot everything? Slowness within vCenter can indicate a sql issue of sorts. Check all applicable items for available resources, *including* disk space on all partitions.